How to apply patch to switch/update a layer version(yocto)?
I am working with yocto mickledore layers version. I needed to use meta-ti. I can't find a mickledore version of meta-ti, so as I found out that I need to apply a patch to switch layer compatibility. I found this patch that I think something similar will do the job:
diff --git a/meta-ti-bsp/conf/layer.conf b/meta-ti-bsp/conf/layer.conf
index 8d80fc55..68651b8d 100644
--- a/meta-ti-bsp/conf/layer.conf
+++ b/meta-ti-bsp/conf/layer.conf
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-ti-bsp"
 BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-ti-bsp := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
 BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-ti-bsp = "6"
 
-LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-ti-bsp = "kirkstone langdale mickledore"
+LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-ti-bsp = "kirkstone langdale mickledore nanbield"
 
 LICENSE_PATH += "${LAYERDIR}/licenses"
 
diff --git a/meta-ti-extras/conf/layer.conf b/meta-ti-extras/conf/layer.conf
index 3665a4f0..a7cca42e 100644
--- a/meta-ti-extras/conf/layer.conf
+++ b/meta-ti-extras/conf/layer.conf
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-ti-extras"
 BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-ti-extras := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
 BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-ti-extras = "6"
 
-LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-ti-extras = "kirkstone langdale mickledore"
+LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-ti-extras = "kirkstone langdale mickledore nanbield"
 
 LICENSE_PATH += "${LAYERDIR}/licenses"

I cloned meta-ti layer of kirkstone version and when I added meta-ti-bsp and meta-ti-extras to bblayers.conf I have this error:
Layer meta-ti-bsp is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: mickledore (layer is compatible with kirkstone langdale). 

Should that patch solve my problem? If so, how can I apply this patch to my yocto project to be able to update/switch meta-ti layer compatibility?
Otherwise, what will be the solution to use a layer that it has not a compatible version that matches my yocto project?
